# PHP: How to find most used array key?

Tags: php, arrays

Lets say I have a simple 1D array with 10-20 entries. Some will be duplicate, How would I find out which entry is used the most? like..

```
$code = Array("test" , "cat" , "test" , "this", "that", "then");
```

How would I show "test" as the most used entry?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$code = Array("test" , "cat" , "test" , "this", "that", "then");

function array_most_common($input) { 
  $counted = array_count_values($input); 
  arsort($counted); 
  return(key($counted));     
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_most_common($code));
```

Comment: Sorting the entire array just to find the maximum seems a bit wasteful.

Comment: @Thomas is there an obvious, faster alternative seeing as the array does not come pre-sorted? Not arguing, just asking.

Comment: @Thomas Sort will be faster than linear loop over the array. If you wish you can always remove the arsort() and do a for loop to determine which one is with highest count.

Comment: @Pekka: Sort is O(_n_ log _n_), and you should be able to determine the maximum in O(_n_) time. But maybe PHP's implementation of `arsort` versus rolling your own `for` loop makes the sort come out faster in practice; I don't know.

Answer (score 5):

You can get a count of the number of occurrences of each value by using [array_count_values](http://php.net/array_count_values).

```
$code = array("test" , "cat" , "cat", "test" , "this", "that", "then");
$counts = array_count_values($code);
var_dump($counts);
/*
array(5) {
  ["test"]=>
  int(2)
  ["cat"]=>
  int(2)
  ["this"]=>
  int(1)
  ["that"]=>
  int(1)
  ["then"]=>
  int(1)
}
*/
```

To get the most frequently occurring value, you can call [max](http://php.net/max) on the array and then access the (first) value with [array_search](http://php.net/array_search).

```
$code = array("test" , "cat" , "cat", "test" , "this", "that", "then");
$counts = array_count_values($code);
$max = max($counts);
$top = array_search($max, $counts);
var_dump($max, $top);
/*
int(2)
string(4) "test"
*/
```

If you wish to cater for multiple most-frequent values, then something like the following would work:

```
$code = array("test" , "cat" , "cat", "test" , "this", "that", "then");
$counts = array_count_values($code);
$max = max($counts);
$top = array_keys($counts, $max);
var_dump($max, $top);
/*
int(2)
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "test"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "cat"
}
*/
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)