# PHP Get Highest Count Value from Array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

In an array I have to find the object that is most recurring

```
$items = array("370","370","546","55");
$value = max($items);
$key = array_search($value, $items);
```

This print out 2 and 546.

But how can I output **2** and its related value, so in my example **370**?

Comment: Your array has no _key_ 370. The keys of your array are 0, 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: What should be the output ? 2 or 370?

Comment: You means both?

Comment: [`max()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) returns the highest value, it doesn't care how many times this value occurs in the array. `546` is the highest value from `$item` and `2` is its index (position) in the array. It is not a count.

Comment: What is the expected output in the event of a tie?  Display all highest occurrences?  Just one? If so, which one?

Comment: @mickmackusa already answered, here the full working fiddle http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d3f82fa5dcb596321607ce02485ff87414a198d9

Comment: It seems you don't care if there are multiple highest values then.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: @mickmackusa good point...:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: How to find most used array key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587802/php-how-to-find-most-used-array-key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took @alistaircol Idea and not only fixed it (as it's dependent on the order of the array) but I also simplfied the assignment part so we are not creating 2 new arrays

You can try it here

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2fe11fb6040dc68db43fb5cbb858ef3e47394dd2

And here is the code

```
$items   = [370,370,546,55,55,55];
$counted = array_count_values($items);

arsort($counted); //sort descending maintain keys

$occurences = reset($counted); //get the first value (rewinds internal pointer )
$most_frequent = key($counted); //get the key, as we are rewound it's the first key

echo $most_frequent . ' appears ' . $occurences . ' time(s)' . PHP_EOL;
```

This correctly outputs

```
55 appears 3 time(s)
```

Just FYI @alistaircol original answer would fail this test case

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fe13e7a0bd00ea1219bc69e2bc5a5aebaf478034

Which is changing the input array from:

```
  $items   = [370,370,546,55];
```

To:

```
  $items   = [370,370,546,55,55,55];
```

It would still output:

```
  370 appears 2 time(s)
```

In this case when the correct answer is `55 appears 3 time(s)`

This way the item with the most is the last one, which exposes that it's based on the order ( which was obvious to me because of using the first index `[0]` )

Not to call him out on it, but as it was accepted as the answer I felt I should point that out.  Overall though I was a sound approach to the question.  So Kudos on that.

**UPDATE**

One way to get all values that show more then one time is like this:

```
$items   = [370,370,546,55,55,55];

$unique = array_unique( $items );

$diff = array_diff_assoc( $items, $unique);

print_r( $diff );
```

Which outputs

```
Array
(
   [1] => 370
   [4] => 55
   [5] => 55
)
```

You can test it here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/53df6a8ea7a68768572cfef494e3b715aa13e83b

One note, is that you will get exactly one less occurrence then is actually present.

**UPDATE1**

We can easily combine these and account for the missing one.  See this fiddle to test that

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1bc1a30a5e091af3a18fec2c8b48050869108549

And the code:

```
$items   = [370,370,546,55,55,55];

$unique = array_unique( $items );

$diff = array_diff_assoc( $items, $unique);

print_r( $diff );
echo "\n\n";

$counted = array_count_values($diff);

arsort($counted); //sort descending maintain keys

$occurences = reset($counted); //get the first value (rewinds internal pointer )
$most_frequent = key($counted); //get the key, as we are rewound it's the first key

echo $most_frequent . ' appears ' . ( $occurences + 1 ) . ' time(s)' . PHP_EOL;
```

Outputs ( both the previous ones )

```
Array
(
    [1] => 370
    [4] => 55
    [5] => 55
)

55 appears 3 time(s)
```

Oh and if you want the ones that are more then one as a list with no duplicates, then just hit it again with array unique  `$unique = array_unique($diff);`

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for final clarification...however in your example how can I get the second value too? 370 2

Comment: Do you want everything that appears more than once, and this, or this.  If you follow.

Comment: I saw your fiddle as comment in the other answer. It's perfect for me so I can use it also like `echo $number_appears_most[1] . ' appears ' . $number_of_occurences[1] . ' time(s)' . PHP_EOL;`

Comment: what about this problem `$items   = [370,370,370,546,55,55,55];` ?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a problem it's a tie.  You have to decide how you want to handle that.

Answer (score 2):

I use `array_count_values` and from the resulting array use `array_keys` to get the numbers which appear most (e.g. 370) and `array_values` to get the number of times it appears (e.g. 2).

```
<?php
$items   = [370,370,546,55];
$counted = array_count_values($items);
/*
Array
(
    [370] => 2
    [546] => 1
    [55] => 1
)

*/

$number_appears_most = array_keys($counted);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => 370
    [1] => 546
    [2] => 55
)
*/

$number_of_occurences = array_values($counted);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
)
*/    
echo $number_appears_most[0] . ' appears ' . $number_of_occurences[0] . ' time(s)' . PHP_EOL;
```

This will give you:

```
370 appears 2 time(s)
```

Demo: https://eval.in/890626

Comment: Your code is based on the order, see this fiddle http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fe13e7a0bd00ea1219bc69e2bc5a5aebaf478034

Comment: The correct answer should be `55 appears 3 time(s)` however its unchanged.  To remedy this you have to sort by the number of occurrences, I would recommend doing `arsort ($counted);`

Comment: See this fiddle where I fixed it for you: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d3f82fa5dcb596321607ce02485ff87414a198d9

Comment: Sure, I added an answer with a few other fixes ( or tweaks ) if you don't mind,  I was a really good approach though.  Give it a look, as I simplified assigng the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can find same value count like this way.

```
print_r(array_count_values($items));
```

will output

```
Array
(
   [370] => 2
   [546] => 1
   [55] => 1
   etc...
)
```

To get 2 and 307 value you have to do below things.

```
$new_arr = array_count_values($items);
$max = max($new_arr);
$new_arr = array_keys($new_arr, max($new_arr)));
echo $new_arr[0]."is repeated (".$max.") times.";
```

will output

```
  307 is repeated (2) times.
```

Comment: I can't use it, I don't know the number 370

Answer (score 1):

```
$items   = [370,370,546,55,55];
$counted = array_count_values($items);  // count occurrences
$counted=array_intersect ($counted,[max($counted)]);  // only keep elements with highest occurrence
var_export ($counted);  // print to screen
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a php function `array_count_values` that should work in your case.

Then you have an array with a count of all values and you can sort and work with them.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

```
$items = array("370","370","546","55");
print_r(array_count_values($items));
```

Comment: Thanks, I already know, but how can I use it to output 370 and 2?